# Redis Cache (Redisson Client) not getting updated with DB (Mysql, Hibernate) updates

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, redis, redisson

I am able to cache the DB entity, but when I update it and do a get call to the same entity, I receive the stale the entity in response. Am I missing come configuration here?

BTW I am trying to implement L2 cache to be used by hibernate for performance improvement.

RedisConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}") int redisPort;
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}") String redisHost;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisHost);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisHost, redisPort);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());

        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: org.redisson.hibernate.RedissonRegionFactory
          redisson:
            fallback: true
            config: redisson-dev.yaml
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    cache:
      type: redis
```

redisson-dev.yaml

```
singleServerConfig:
  address: "redis://localhost:6379"
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Slf4j
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region="userCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name="user")
public class userEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID userId;//Binary in DB and UUID here
.
.
.
}
```